# targetting form elements using array values in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I have a small form in javascript with two Input values with the same class name. I know that you can target them by giving them ids but is there a way to target them using array values?

```
 <td>
  <input class="inputtextb" type="text" name="adults" maxlength="3">&nbsp;Adults&nbsp;
<input class="inputtextb" type="text" name="children" maxlength="3">&nbsp;Children   above 5 years&nbsp;
```

Comment: What array? What values? `document.getElementsByName()`?

Comment: I did not think of that, thanks. My concept was that since elements in the DOM are stored in arrays, maybe i could access them using array values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) for that:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('inputtextb');

inputs[0] // the first input
inputs[1] // the second input
```

In case that doesn't work - [can i use getElementsByClassName](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname) - you could iterate over all `<input>` elements using `document.getElementsByName()` and filter out the ones you want; or use jQuery ;-)

Comment: Of course, as with anything in JS, older versions of IE don't support `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
var adults = document. getElementsByClassName('inputtextb')[0].value 
var children = document. getElementsByClassName('inputtextb')[1].value
```

In Firefox 3, you can convert it into an Array and then call `forEach` on it:

```
var inputVals = document.getElementsByClassName("inputtextb");
var elsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputVals, 0);
elsArray.forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el.tagName);
});
```

**Note :** It does not return an Array, it returns a `NodeList` objects.